# Laravel: How to get nested relationships from two parents

Tags: laravel, relationship

I am having trouble articulating my Laravel question, so please bear with me while I try to explain my problem.

I am trying to make a web interface where users can create one or more copies of a page component (for example a hero banner or a popup modal). These components have been pre-defined by developers.  I have the following table structure:

[image]

- The `components` table is the highest level table. It contains blueprints for unique components
- Every component has a different number of different properties, so these properties are stored in the `component_properties` table
- An end-user is able to create multiple instances of each component. These are saved in the `component_instances` table
- The end-user is then able to enter values for each of the properties defined in the component_properties table.

What I am trying to do is get the following JSON structure returned from my controller

```
components
    component_instances
        component properties
            component_instance_values
```

for example:

```
{
    'component': {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'sample component',
        'instances': [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'properties': [
                    {
                        'id': 1,
                        'name': 'property 1',
                        'values': {
                            'id': 1,
                            'value': 'value 1',
                    }                   
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is there is no direct relationship between component_instances and component_properties so this structure doesn't seem to be achievable.  I can get `components > instances > values > property`, and in most cases, this is acceptable. But when an instance is first created, it doesn't have any values. Therefore, I cannot get to the component_properties.

Is there anyway I can get the structure I need? I have tried looking for core Laravel methods but have not found any. I have also tried getting each table as separate variables and merging them manually in my controller but this seems to be performance heavy and I still haven't got exactly what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, component_instance_values is your pivot table for component_instances and component_properties so it will not be possible to get a property before there is any value-added in instance_values. You can create a separate pivot table for this instance and attach values to it so if the values are not yet added you can still get properties.

To get your required structure you can use the following code.
Define your relations

```
class Component extends Model
{
   public function instances()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(ComponentInstance::class);
   }
}

class ComponentInstance extends Model
{    
   public function component()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Component::class);
   }
    
   public function properties()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(ComponentProperty::class, 'component_instance_values', 'component_instance_id', 'component_property_id');
    }
}

class ComponentProperty extends Model
{
    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ComponentInstanceValue::class);
    }
}
```

You can be using something like below in your controller to get the required JSON format

```
$components = Component::with(['instances.properties' => function ($query) {
    $query->with('values');
}])->get();
```

> Note: above code is for the structure of your current tables if you add another pivot table you can update the properties relation in ComponentInstance to have your desired values.

Comment: can also use `->withPivot('value')` on the `properties` relation to load a field from the pivot table